# api generated svg's not rendering in github markdown files

Tags: github, svg

Hi I am working on a StackApp called Stack Exchange Readme Stats

It works as the following:
[image: Tessa's stackoverflow stats] [image: Tessa's stackoverflow stats] [image: Tessa's ask ubuntu stats]

The markdown:

```
![Tessa's stackoverflow stats](https://api.squeeble.ink/se/?userId=7185314&seSite=stackoverflow) 
![Tessa's meta exchange stats](https://api.squeeble.ink/se/?userId=388239&seSite=meta)
![Tessa's ask ubuntu stats](https://api.squeeble.ink/se/?userId=796646&seSite=AskUbuntu)
```

The [codebase](https://github.com/squeeble-ink/stackexchange.readme-stats)

However using the markdown above will only output the alt texts.
I was wondering why something like below does render the svg
[image: Tessa's github stats]
This is made by [anuraghazra](https://github.com/anuraghazra/github-readme-stats)

Comment: Your links seem to be working fine for me locally and it's also working in this post right? I did get only the alt text when I specified the wrong `userId` or `seSite` though. When the `userId` and `seSite` don't correspond the request times out and the image doesn't show.

Comment: I don't see them rendered on GitHub in my markdown (I wanted to add them to my personal GitHub readme)

Comment: I see, yeah I get a 502 Bad Gateway on github. Are you using nginx? Maybe its something to do with your configuration?

Comment: I am using Heroku as hosting

Comment: I'm getting a certificate problem for that domain.  That's likely what's causing the problem.

Comment: How is the certificate a problem? To my knowledge it is a valid certificate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I had the idea that the issue might be the image in the SVG. This idea came from the fact that the GitHub stats made by [anuraghazra](https://github.com/anuraghazra/github-readme-stats) do not contain any images. So I worked on a feature that you can turn off the image and that it will show your user name:

[image: Tessa's stackoverflow stats]
[image: Tessa's meta exchange stats]
[image: Tessa's ask ubuntu stats]

```
![Tessa's stackoverflow stats](https://api.squeeble.ink/se/?userId=7185314&seSite=stackoverflow&img=false&nameX=22) 
![Tessa's meta exchange stats](https://api.squeeble.ink/se/?userId=388239&seSite=meta&img=false&nameX=22)
![Tessa's ask ubuntu stats](https://api.squeeble.ink/se/?userId=796646&seSite=AskUbuntu&img=false&nameX=22)
```

Only finding out with testing on GitHub that I forgot the `s` in the `https`. Now my SVG worked with `http`. I noticed it because the other 2 SVGs I wanted to add had `https` in the link. Those with `https` only showed the alt text unregarded that I requested the SVGs without the image.

#### Conclusion

SVGs won't always work with `https` in the request link on GitHub. As user @bk2204 commented that it was a certificate issue. Is true since they do work with `http`.

Answer (score 1):

I've been working on a similar thing myself which involves building and serving svg cards to be rendered in github markdown, and I did encounter this issue.

the solution here is to simply specify the `mimetype` as `image/svg+xml` in your response headers.

the method for sending the headers would differ based on the language you're using

for example, in my case where i'm using python (flask) to serve the svgs, it's enough to pass the value to the `mimetype` parameter to a flask `Response` object as in

```py
@app.route('/svg')
def build_svg():
    res = flask.Response(svg, mimetype="image/svg+xml")  # where svg is the data  to be sent
    return res
```

it's just necessary to pass that param in the headers and it would render correctly in readmes.

Comment: Thanks for the added information! However in my case I already set the `mime-type` / `content-type` [MDN MIME types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types)